# Why does Unity call certain methods "messages"?

Tags: unity, c#, terminology

I just surprised that the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) calls methods like Update or Start or Awake "Messages" rather than methods.

[image]

Does that mean those methods are used to send a message to something?

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `Start` or `Update` are called message methods because these methods get called through the Unity Message System.

You might notice that all those methods don't have an access modifier in the standard template for new MonoBehaviours. When you are familiar with the C# programming language outside of the context of Unity, then you might realize that this means they are actually declared `private`.
Which means it should not be possible for them to get called from anywhere except from inside the same class. So how is it possible for those methods to get called by the engine at all? It's because the Unity messaging system uses [runtime reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to find and call private methods of your scripts.

You can actually use the Unity messaging system yourself. The method [`gameObject.SendMessage(string methodName)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) scans all scripts on the gameObject for methods of that name (no matter if public, internal, protected or private) and calls all of them. I would not *recommend* that for various software architecture reasons, but you can.

*Why* did Unity choose to implement the most essential part of their API architecture in a way [most experienced developers disdain](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sendmessage-is-a-trap.430067/) and [they themselves no longer recommend anymore](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/MessagingSystem.html)? Because in the early days of the engine, their primary target demographic were novice developers. So they prioritized code simplicity over performance and clean architecture. Their demographic shifted in the past couple years to a more professional audience, but it's hard to get rid of early sins in such a a well-established software product (unless you [reinvent your whole scripting API from scratch](https://unity.com/dots)).

Comment: Readers may also be interested in [this related answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/164893/39518), which goes into a bit more detail about the approach used to call the built-in message methods. Just to reassure folks, Unity isn't performing this reflection on every call, many times a frame. Instead it sensibly caches the method information once so you don't have reflection in your core game loop (unless you're calling `SendMessage` yourself).