# How to call every method with a certain name from a set of classes in C#

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, game-loop, monobehaviour

I have the following case:
I have a class called `App.cs` and here I have a function called Render, that runs once every frame:

```
public static class Render(){
   DrawBuffer.Clear(); //clear the last frame
   //DrawStuff, Logic, etc.

   DepthBuffer.Calculate(); //compute the depth of the scene for the current frame
}
```

Now, I want to be able to add game logic, and drawing objects, but not directly from within `App.cs` for cleanness, so I'm trying to implement a system of "scripting" for my own 3D render engine similar to Unity3D.
So, lets suppose I have the following scripts: `Script1.cs`, `Script2.cs` and `Script3.cs`. I want to be able to have certain names for methods within those scripts that do certain things. For example let's say that scripts can definte the method `GameLoop()` which would be the equivalent of `Update()` from Unity and `Init()` which would be the equivalent of `Start()` from Unity. Let's focus on `GameLoop()` first. `Script1.cs` might look something like this:

```
using MyRenderEngine;
using System;

public class Script1
{
   public void Init(){
      //Called at the beginning
   }
   public void GameLoop(){
      //Called every frame
   }
}
```

`Script2.cs` and `Script3.cs` would look very similar to this.

Now, the subject of this question is how would I make every GameLoop() of every script be called in the main game loop? 
The most obvious method would be in `App.cs` to have in the `Render()` method:

```
Script1 script1 = new Script1();
Script2 script2 = new Script2();
Script3 script3 = new Script3();
   
public static void Render(){
   //Clear last frame
   script1.GameLoop();
   script2.GameLoop();
   script3.GameLoop();
   //Compute depth buffer   
}
```

But would be very awkward to have to add a call in the main render loop(`Render()`) for each script.
I can create a list of `object` that can hold a reference to each script and to add a foreach loop in the `Render()` to call the `GameLoop()` from within each of them, but I would need to add scripts to that list manually, which would be the same as calling the method directly.

The second solution I found would be to create an interface, let's say `Behaviour3D` that each script need to implement and that contain the methods `GameLoop()` and `Init()` that can be overrode by each class implementing `Behaviour3D`, but I would need to create a list and update it manually. I could maybe use `Reflexion` to obtain automatically a list of all classes that implement `Behaviour3D` interface, but I have a motto: "Avoid Reflection as much a possible". Now I have 2 questions:

1. How does Unity do it?(How MonoBehaviour works)
2. How would you do it?

Comment: Regarding reflection:https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164892/why-does-unity-use-reflection-to-get-the-update-method

Comment: Your options are 1) use reflection (which you say you don't want) and 2) register the objects in a list of an interface or delegate type (which you also say you don't want). Sadly, you will have to pick one. Unity internally has lists of objects or function pointers, as the link Zibelas shared explains. This is why objects in Unity are created through the `Instantiate` / `AddComponent` methods and not constructed directly, so that inside those methods Unity can do the work of adding the object to the appropriate lists, without burdening the user with maintaining them manually.

Comment: @DMGregory Your 2) "you will have to pick one." point missed a third option, base class with automatic registration to a static `List` in the constructor.

Comment: That's still registering objects in a list and calling them virtually, the same as a list of an interface type. But it has another issue, as discussed in the thread Zibelas links above: It removes your ability to *not* call one of these methods when it's not needed. You always get a virtual method call, even if that just calls into the default implementation and immediately returns. [The performance cost of this adds up](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/10000-update-calls) if, say, you have hundreds of objects that don't need any `BeforeUpdate()` processing but they get called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a base **abstract class** `Behaviour3D`.

There is no need for reflection.

```
public abstract class Behaviour3D
{
   internal static List<Behaviour3D> myObjects = new();
   internal static List<Behaviour3D> myObjectsRemove = new();

   // ...
   public Behaviour3D()
   {
      myObjects.Add(this);
      // ...
   }

   public virtual BeforeUpdate()
   { 
   }

   public virtual Update()
   {
   }
   public virtual Render()
   {
   }

   // Removal methods
   public void Remove()
   {
      myObjectsRemove.Add(this);
   }
   public static void Remove(Behaviour3D r)
   {
      myObjectsRemove.Add(r);
   }
   public static void RemoveAll()
   {
      myObjects.Clear();
      myObjectsRemove.Clear();
   }

   internal static void InternalGameLoop(){
      //Clear last frame

      // remove deleted objects
      foreach(var removeItem in Behaviour3D.myObjectsRemove)
         item.Behaviour3D.myObjects.Remove(removeItem);
      myObjectsRemove.Clear();

      foreach(var item in Behaviour3D.myObjects)
         item.BeforeUpdate();
      foreach(var item in Behaviour3D.myObjects)
         item.Update();
      foreach(var item in Behaviour3D.myObjects)
         item.Render();

      //Compute depth buffer   
   }
```

Each derived class has the opportunity to override the methods as they see fit:

- `BeforeUpdate()`
- `Update()`
- `Render()`

Any parameters such as timing can be provided by protected variables.

Your main programs base entry point,`App.cs` simply calls every step:

`Behaviour3D.InternalGameLoop()` passing any of the needed protected variables.